# SetWindowsHookEx only hook specific keyboard

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, keyboard, low-level

I am trying to capture all keypress from a RFID scanner that is functioning as a Wedge keyboard.

I have a class that uses SetWindowsHooEx to get all keyboard key presses. That means it's also capturing the actual keyboard.

I am wondering if there is a way that I could specify which keyboard to hook to by Name or HID (preferably name)?

If there is a way, a code sample would be greatly appreciated.
Below is the Keyboard hook class that I am using, for reference.

```
Public Class KeyboardHook

    <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Private Overloads Shared Function SetWindowsHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal HookProc As KBDLLHookProc, ByVal hInstance As IntPtr, ByVal wParam As Integer) As Integer
    End Function
    <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Private Overloads Shared Function CallNextHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function
    <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Private Overloads Shared Function UnhookWindowsHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Private Structure KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
        Public vkCode As UInt32
        Public scanCode As UInt32
        Public flags As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags
        Public time As UInt32
        Public dwExtraInfo As UIntPtr
    End Structure

    <Flags()>
    Private Enum KBDLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags As UInt32
        LLKHF_EXTENDED = &H1
        LLKHF_INJECTED = &H10
        LLKHF_ALTDOWN = &H20
        LLKHF_UP = &H80
    End Enum

    Public Shared Event KeyDown(ByVal Key As Keys)
    Public Shared Event KeyUp(ByVal Key As Keys)

    Private Const WH_KEYBOARD_LL As Integer = 13
    Private Const HC_ACTION As Integer = 0
    Private Const WM_KEYDOWN = &H100
    Private Const WM_KEYUP = &H101
    Private Const WM_SYSKEYDOWN = &H104
    Private Const WM_SYSKEYUP = &H105

    Private Delegate Function KBDLLHookProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer

    Private KBDLLHookProcDelegate As KBDLLHookProc = New KBDLLHookProc(AddressOf KeyboardProc)
    Private HHookID As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

    Private Function KeyboardProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
        If (nCode = HC_ACTION) Then
            Dim struct As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
            Select Case wParam
                Case WM_KEYDOWN, WM_SYSKEYDOWN
                    RaiseEvent KeyDown(CType(CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, struct.GetType()), KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT).vkCode, Keys))
                Case WM_KEYUP, WM_SYSKEYUP
                    RaiseEvent KeyUp(CType(CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, struct.GetType()), KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT).vkCode, Keys))
            End Select
        End If
        Return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam)
    End Function

    Public Sub New()
        HHookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KBDLLHookProcDelegate, Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetModules()(0)).ToInt32, 0)
        If HHookID = IntPtr.Zero Then
            Throw New Exception("Could not set keyboard hook")
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        If Not HHookID = IntPtr.Zero Then
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(HHookID)
        End If
        MyBase.Finalize()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: RawInput is your needed API, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: [Codeproject RawInput Article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard) that includes how to identify the device

Comment: Also you can use SharpDX.RawInput: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpDX.RawInput/

Comment: Thank you soohoonigan and DogeAmazed for pointing me at the right direction. That's exactly what I needed.